# Идентификатор врага на миникарте

Tags: c#, unity3d

Создал мини карту,
столкнулся с проблемой такого рода:
Когда герой на земле то размер идентификатора врага нормальный, Но мой герой летает и при наборе высоты идентификаторы уменьшаются.
Создал мини карту благодаря [этому](https://habrahabr.ru/post/304632/) ресурсу. 
Как решить проблему при полёте

Comment: Там для объектов добавлялись сферы в конце. Задай им константную координату высоты(Y)

Comment: Хотя я бы миникарту делал иначе. Еще одна камера в теории сильно увеличит количество расчетов для отрисовки, поэтому я бы сделал снимок всей карты, а потом  бы брал координаты персонажей  и пересчитывал их в миникарту(ставил бы на их позициях какой то спрайт, красный круг к примеру).

Comment: очень хорошая идея, есть какой то пример может ? Большое спасибо!

Comment: @Abs3akt есть готовые системы для карт, например KGFMapSystem. Можно на asset store посмотреть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как сделать грамотно:

текстура фона(ортографический рендер или рисованная карта),

поверх неё текстуры обозначающие персонажей,

дальше понадобится немного кода, который будет мировые координаты персонажей(только х и z если это 3д) приводить к экранным координатам относительно фона.

Если нужно -- просчитывается смещенеи от нужного предмета.

вот тебе правильная карта.

---

А если хочешь доработать этот костыльный метод --- заблочь у сфер возможность двигатся по "y" оси координат через инспектор.

PS: При чем приблизительно это же написано в коментариях к самой статье, на которую ты и ссылаешься.